# Azure search wildcards and dash character

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have an index containing item:

`{ "samplefield": "bd1b0d5d-743e-4b3c-a0e9-e9e4e0766429" }`

I try to use search expression on this field as follows: "bd1b0d5d\\-743e\\-4b3c\\-a0*".

Unfortunately combining escaping character "-" with wildcard "*" does not work. Don`t understand why this works that way? When I provided full search word it works properly.

Search parameters are: SearchMode.All and QueryType.Full to use Lucene syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is because it's considered each piece separated by '-' as a different word. You have two options.

1-"samplefield eq 'bd1b0d5d' and samplefield  eq '743e' and samplefield  eq 'a0e9' and samplefield   eq 'e9e4e0766429'

2-change the analyzer for this particular field from StandardAnalyzer to WhitespaceAnalyzer

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers#AnalyzerTable

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
"bd1b0d5d\\-743e\\-4b3c\\-a0*/"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives an exception: "Failed to parse query string at line 1, column 43. See https://aka.ms/azure-search-full-query for supported syntax."